# Exchange 2010 calendar sharing

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

The users in questiong work with Outlook 2010 on an Exchange 2010 server. They share a calendar and can all view and update it. However, there is a need for a new class of users who  need to be read only and only see that an entry on a given date and time is booked, without being able to see any details about it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they need the Free/Busy Time permission level.